# Populate GeoExt 2 gridpanel from OpenLayers vector features

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, json, geoext-2

I need to populate a ExtJS datagrid with a OpenLayers features. The official example http://geoext.github.io/geoext2/examples/grid/feature-grid.html doesn't help me, because the data is loaded from a JSON file, but I need the features parsed from a WFS layer.

Could anyone help me with a source code example (jsfiddle)?

Comment: Why no JSON? You can do nicely WFS requests and use JSON as output format.

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: WFS data is stored as json object by openlayers so the example is still useful. post your code then we can help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you should load your wfs as a vector layer:

```
            var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    url:  "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
                    featureType: "tasmania_roads",
                    featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
                })
            });
```

Then you'll have all attribute information available via `layer.features[index].attributes` for each feature. This way you can easily build an object to pass to the feature grid (ie, reproduce the example json) and customize which attributes you want to load in the feature store.